# How do you get the unmarshaller in JAXB to ignore the XML root element name?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, fxg

I am reading some XML data (FXG files if you are familiar with them).

Part of the data has varying tag names:

```
<varying_name1 scaleX="1.0046692" x="177.4" y="74.2"/>
<varying_name2  scaleX="1.0031128" x="171.9" y="118.9"/>
```

I have created a class named Transforms to represent the data within the varying tag name segment. In my JAXB class to hold the data I have:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)    
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TransformAdapter.class)    
protected List<Transform> transforms;
```

In my Adapter, I attempt to unmarshal the data:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transform.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Transform result = (Transform) unmarshaller.unmarshal(v);
```

However, my code throws an exception here because the root name on my element varies.  It is not a constant.  I get:

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008", local:"m6_mc"). Expected elements are (none)
```

How can I get it to just unmarshal my data as if the root element had the name it expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default a a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will determine the class to unmarshal based on the root element.  This is matched with metadata provided via an `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` annotation.

Alternately you one of the unmarshal methods that take a class parameter.  This tells JAXB what class you wish to unmarshal to.  The result of the unmarshal will be an instance of `JAXBElement` that in addition to the Java object will contain root element info in case you need it.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transform.class); 
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller(); 
Transform result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(v, Transform.class).getValue();
```

Comment: I don't understand why providing the class argument a second time tells it to disregard root element, however, that works!  I should have copied your example that I downloaded a little more closely.

Comment: @Joe - I've expanded my answer, hopefully that helps clarify things.